# Away3D depth buffering

Tags: flash, stage3d, away3d, depth-buffer

I'm developing a simple scene editor in Away3D, where the user can import, arrange and transform objects. In order to simplify the user process, I've created a gizmo object which appears over the selection (basically three arrows for click-dragging), but this can be obscured by other objects if they're in front of the selection, relative to the camera - is there any way to turn off depth-buffering for a given object/group, so that it is *always* rendered in front of the other objects in scene?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to do it in away3d, but is stage3D API this can be achieved by using context3D.setDepthTest() with Context3DCompareMode.ALWAYS parameter.

Comment: Another solution would be to arrange draw calls in such order so that the object that should not be obscured would be drawn after everything else.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this but I got sidetracked - I don't really know what you mean by the above, how would I reach this property from the object I wish to remain on top? Cheers